# images in an array get removed when individually appending them to another element

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays

```
    <?php 
$imgdir =   'dirimages/';
$images =   glob($imgdir    .   '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}',GLOB_BRACE);

?>

<script>
jQuery(function(){  
    var phpvar  =   <?php echo json_encode($images) ?>;
    $.each(phpvar,function(id,image){
        jQuery('#slidediv').append('<img class="loadimg" src="' + image + '"/>');
        });
    $('#slidediv').on('click','.loadimg',function(){
        $(this).popup("show");
    });

});
```

Whenever I click one of the images, it loads the 'overlay' plugin with .popup also tried with .append(). However every time I click one of the images, it removes it from the array of images. Is there a way to 'freeze' the array or just take the image as a reference instead of 'stealing' the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on the code of your `popup()` function, but my guess is that you are appending the element somewhere else, effectively removing it from its old location.

A simple solution would be to [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) it:

```
$('#slidediv').on('click','.loadimg',function(){
    $(this).clone().popup("show");
});
```

Comment: works great thanks :) just one question though, I haven't used the .clone() method before - would this add extra weight to the server since you're effectively loading the images twice? or does it simply use the image as a reference?

Comment: @joe No, just check the net tab in the developers tools, no new request is made.